# How to draw animation over a webview in android

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I want to draw animations over a webview. My activity's xml structure looks like the structure below:

```
 <FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>

        <WebView/>

    <LinearLayout>      
    </LinearLayout> 
 </FrameLayout>
```

Is it possible somehow to create a transparent canvas in order to draw my animation over the webview?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Actually done it by creating a CustomWebView object that extends WebView and add it to the layout programmaticaly. The CustomWebView objects overrides onDraw(Canvas canvas) method, and there I do my animation...

Comment: I just want to add, that according to Android API, this method is not recommended for advanced graphic animations that need to refresh in a short period. It recommends SurfaceView instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `RelativeLayout` as a parent of the `WebView` you would be able to add some other view above it, order of declaration in the `XML` file determines the way it is drawn, so if the `WebView` is drawn first then the next view will be on top of it, make the background of this view transparent and you should be good to go, you may have some problems with interacting with the `WebView` however, I would make the visibility of this view `View.GONE` while it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have already done this method but only for simple layouts. The problem is that for the canvas as far as I know I need to set onCreate method with setContentView(myView), where myView = object of a CanvasView class that extends View and overrides onDraw method to set canvas. On the other hand for the layout I need in setContentView() method to set the activity's xml. Do you know a way to set the  CanvasView in a RelativeLayout? thanks!